# How to create in controller a JSON model from a local JSON file in SAPUI5 V1.38.39?

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

### Environnement :

Framework : **SAPUI5 V.1.38.39**
IDE : WebIde

### Requirement :

I created a JSON file **Data.json** in the **model folder** and i would like to use in in the **onInit** of my **controller** to **create a JSONmodel**, my actual problem is that it's always **returning me a 404 response** on Data.json .
The **folder tree** it the initial one **from SAPUI5 application template**

### Problem in code & test :

**test 1** in webapp/controller/App.contoller.js:

```js
onInit: function () {
  var oBusy = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
  var oModel = new JSONModel();
  oModel.attachRequestSent(function() {
    oBusy.open();
  });
  oModel.loadData("model/Data.json"); //here the path so I suppose here the problem
  oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
    oBusy.close();
  });
  this.getView().setModel(oModel, "CompaniesModel")
}
```

**test 2** in webapp/controller/App.contoller.js:

```js
onInit: function () {
  var oBusy = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
  var oModel = new JSONModel();
  oModel.attachRequestSent(function() {
    oBusy.open();
  });
  oModel.loadData("../model/Data.json"); //here the path so I suppose here the problem
  oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
    oBusy.close();
  });
  this.getView().setModel(oModel, "CompaniesModel")
}
```

**test 3** in webapp/controller/App.contoller.js:

```js
onInit: function () {
  var oBusy = new sap.m.BusyDialog();
  var oModel = new JSONModel();
  oModel.attachRequestSent(function() {
    oBusy.open();
  });
  oModel.loadData("my/namespace/model/Data.json"); //here the path so I suppose here the problem
  oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function() {
    oBusy.close();
  });
  this.getView().setModel(oModel, "CompaniesModel")
}
```

### APPENDIX - process to reproduce :

In Webide for SAPUI5 create new from template SAPUI5 application selection SAP version 1.38.39, initialize your namespace and your view/controller name.
In model create new Data.json :

```
{
    "Set1": [{
        "Status": "status1",
        "Number": 10
    }, {
        "Status": "status2",
        "Number": 20
    }, {
        "Status": "status3",
        "Number": 30
    }, {
        "Status": "status4",
        "Number": 40
    }]
}
```

in your view :

```
<mvc:View 
    controllerName="your.namespace.controller.App" 
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:viz="sap.viz.ui5.controls"
    xmlns:viz.feeds="sap.viz.ui5.controls.common.feeds"
    xmlns:viz.data="sap.viz.ui5.data"
    xmlns:com="sap.suite.ui.commons" 
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <Shell id="shell">
        <App id="app">
            <pages>
                <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
                    <content>
                        <l:VerticalLayout class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
                            <com:ChartContainer id="chartContainer" showFullScreen="true" showPersonalization="false" autoAdjustHeight="false"
                                personalizationPress="attachPersonalizationPress" contentChange="attachContentChange" title="chart">
                                <com:content>
                                    <com:ChartContainerContent icon="sap-icon://line-chart" title="Line Chart">
                                        <com:content>
                                            <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame_1" height='400px' width="100%" vizType='column' uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}">
                                                <viz:dataset>
                                                    <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{CompaniesModel>/Set1}">
                                                        <viz.data:dimensions>
                                                            <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Status" value="{CompaniesModel>Status}"/>
                                                        </viz.data:dimensions>
                                                        <viz.data:measures>
                                                            <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Number" value="{CompaniesModel>Orders}"/>
                                                        </viz.data:measures>
                                                    </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                                                </viz:dataset>
                                                <viz:feeds>
                                                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="valueAxis" type="Measure" values="Number"/>
                                                    <viz.feeds:FeedItem uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Status"/>
                                                </viz:feeds>
                                            </viz:VizFrame>
                                        </com:content>
                                    </com:ChartContainerContent>
                                </com:content>
                            </com:ChartContainer>
                        </l:VerticalLayout>
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

And in your controller :

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], function (Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("your.namespace.controller.App", {
        onInit: function () {
          //copy here one of the controller described in Problem in code & test
        }
    });
});
```

### EDIT (other option than manifest) :

I add this possibility here if you don't want to use manifest, for using manifest go to the accepted answer of @Cmdd :)
if you don't want to use manifest you can do :

```js
oModel.loadData("../../../../../webapp/model/Data.json");
```

Comment: In your onInit a simple var oModel = new  sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("./model/Data.json");
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "CompaniesModel"); should work but I suggest you to set your model in the init function on the Component. Take a look to the first parte of the linked page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to load the data in the `manifest.json`, as described in [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/10/11/sapui5-load-local-json-model-directly-manifest.json/) link.

In "sap.app" section:

```
"sap.app": {
    ...
    "dataSources": {
        "myModel_alias": {
            "uri": "model/Data.json",
            "type": "JSON"
        }
    }
}
```

in  "sap.ui5" section:

```
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "cmdd.Test.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "CompaniesModel": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "dataSource": "myModel_alias"
        }           
    },
```

Also, don't forgot to put a slash in this binding: `data="{CompaniesModel>/Set1}"` :)